# Testing that a method was called on a Sinatra request

Tags: ruby, api, testing, rspec, sinatra

Hoping someone can help me with some basic Sinatra testing help...

I have a toy sinatra app that implements this basic endpoint, which calls a method of the same name:

```
  get '/hello' do
    hello
  end 

  def hello
    "hello"
  end
```

I then have these 3 specs. The first one and 3rd pass, but the second one fails:

```
  context 'get /hello' do
    let(:app) { App.new! }

    it 'responds to hello' do
      expect(app).to respond_to :hello
    end

    it 'calls hello' do
      expect(app).to receive(:hello)
      get '/hello'
    end 

    it 'returns hello' do
      let(:response) { get '/hello' }

      expect(response.status).to eq 200
      expect(response.body).to eq "hello"
    end

  end
```

Error of it not being called:

```
 expected: 1 time with any arguments
 received: 0 times with any arguments
```

The first spec proves the method exists, and the 3rd spec proves it is actually calling the method in terms of rspec. I'm not sure what I'm missing to get the 2nd spec working

Comment: I suspect that your subject is wrong. What is **sending** the message to *app*? It's probably not the instance of App in your specs.

Comment: I'm using [Rack::Test::Methods](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/brynary/rack-test/master/Rack/Test/Methods), so on the "get", it invokes sending it to the app. To memoize things, I've also moved to using `let(:app) { App.new! }`, so that there is only ever 1 instance of App for this context, yet still no change.

Comment: I suspect the reason this isn’t working is that when [Sinatra handles a request it `dup`s itself](https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/blob/v2.1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb#L927-L930), so a fresh instance is responsible for each request. The `app` instance that is being mocked isn’t the same as the instance actually having the methods called on it.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using `Rack::Test` you need to provide a method named `app` that returns the application to be mocked instead of using a `let` with `App.new!`. Something like this:

```
RSpec.describe 'app' do
  include Rack::Test::Methods

  def app
    Sinatra::Application
  end
  
  context 'get /hello' do
    before { get '/hello' }
    
    it { expect(last_response.status).to eq(200) }
    it { expect(last_response.body).to eq('hello') }
  end
```

More information about the `app` method can be found in the [Sinatra testing docs](http://sinatrarb.com/testing.html).

FWIW I wouldn't write Rack level tests for the first two tests in your example. It unnecessarily couples the implementation to the tests. I'd test the `hello` method directly instead.